# DiscordAPIError[50035]: Invalid Form Body description[BASE_TYPE_REQUIRED]: This field is required

Tags: discord.js

I am new to discrod.js and working on slash command. I made this code from a video on youtube:

```
const { REST, Routes} = require('discord.js')
require('dotenv').config();

const commands = [
    {
        name:'rank',
        descripton: ' Show rank of user on crew3',
    },
];

const rest = new REST({version: '10'}).setToken(process.env.TOKEN);

(async() => {
    try {
        console.log('Registering slash commands');

        await rest.put(
            Routes.applicationGuildCommands(process.env.BOT_ID, process.env.GUILD_ID),
            {body: commands}
        );
        console.log('Slash commands successfully');
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(`${error}`);
    }
})();
```

And this error occur:

```
DiscordAPIError[50035]: Invalid Form Body
description[BASE_TYPE_REQUIRED]: This field is required
    at SequentialHandler.runRequest (C:\Users\User\Desktop\Discord Bot\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\index.js:933:15)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async SequentialHandler.queueRequest (C:\Users\User\Desktop\Discord Bot\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\index.js:712:14)
    at async REST.request (C:\Users\User\Desktop\Discord Bot\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\index.js:1321:22)      
    at async C:\Users\User\Desktop\Discord Bot\src\register-command.js:17:9 {
  rawError: {
    code: 50035,
    errors: { description: [Object] },
    message: 'Invalid Form Body'
  },
  code: 50035,
  status: 400,
  method: 'PUT',
  url: 'https://discord.com/api/v10/applications/1087356643345436783/guilds/1087361011574648922/commands',
  requestBody: { files: undefined, json: [ [Object] ] }
}
```

I try to search for solution but nothing helped. Please help me, I am newbie.

Comment: Typo: `descripton` should be `description`.

Answer (score 1):

You have misspelled `description`.